# Having Trouble Keeping Axes Fixed While Adding Images in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure

I'm currently working on creating a GUI based BlackJack game in MATLAB. I set up two axes for the dealer hand and player hand as follows:

```
self.window = figure('Name', 'Blackjack',...
    'Units', 'normalized',...
    'Position', [.02, .05, .95, .85]);
self.dealerHand = axes('Parent', self.window,...
    'XLimMode', 'manual',...
    'XLim', [0, 10],...
    'YLimMode', 'manual',...
    'YLim', [0, 1],...
    'Title', 'Dealer',...
    'Units', 'normalized',...
    'Position', [.05, .70, .90, .25]);
self.playerHand = axes('Parent', self.window,...
    'XLimMode', 'manual',...
    'XLim', [0, 10],...
    'YLimMode', 'manual',...
    'YLim', [0, 1],...
    'Title', 'Player',...
    'Units', 'normalized',...
    'Position', [.05, .20, .90, .25]);
```

As you can see, I've set both "hands" XLim and YLim modes to manual. However, when I run this script:

```
bjWindow = BlackJackWindow;
deck = DeckOfCards;
deck.shuffle
playerHand{1} = deck.cards{1};
dealerHand{1} = deck.cards{2};
playerHand{2} = deck.cards{3};
dealerHand{2} = deck.cards{4};
hold on
image(bjWindow.dealerHand, [0, 1], [0, 1], dealerHand{1}.img)
image(bjWindow.dealerHand, [1, 2], [0, 1], dealerHand{2}.img)
hold off
hold on
image(bjWindow.playerHand, [0, 1], [1, 0], playerHand{1}.img)
image(bjWindow.playerHand, [1, 2], [1, 0], playerHand{2}.img)
hold off
```

the dealer "hand" auto resizes and stretches the second card like this:

[image: BlackJack error in dealer hand]

If I reverse the order of the hands in the first block of code, the error happens in the player "hand." In other words, whichever axes is created first when the window is initialized has this error. Another question that isn't as important because I've found a workaround, is why does the player "hand" flip the axes such that I have to set the y position to [1, 0] instead of [0, 1]?

Answer (score 0):

The [`hold on`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) affects the current axes, which is the last one you made. When adding an image to the first axes you made, it will be reset. Inverting is part of that, as `image` inverts the y-axis when displaying an image.

The solution is to use

```
hold(bjWindow.dealerHand,'on')
hold(bjWindow.playerHand,'on')
```

I would recommend against turning the hold off again after plotting. There is no need.

Instead, to change what cards are displayed, replace the [image object's `CData` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.primitive.image-properties.html). This is where the pixel data is stored. By updating this property, instead of creating a new image object, your application will be smoother, and you won't need to worry about deleting and re-recreating image objects, preserving axes properties, etc. Updating the property is trivial since all your gliphs (I presume) are of the same sizes.

```
set(image_handle,'CData',playerHand{1}.img)
```